# How can I use both require and import in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Warning: I am very new to javascript so I apologize for my ignorance.

I am currently writing code that needs a dialog keyboard as well as scrolling.
I wrote 2 separate parts, one that creates a keyboard and one that implements scrolling and they work fine on their own.
However, once I try to combine the two together, I find that I am running into errors because I am getting `# Break: it: get THEME: undefined variable!` *edit:* for THEME

```
    import {
        VerticalScroller,
        VerticalScrollbar,
        TopScrollerShadow,
        BottomScrollerShadow
    } from 'scroller';

    var DIALOG = require('mobile/dialog');
    var MODEL = require('mobile/model');
    var THEME = require('themes/sample/theme');
    var KEYBOARD = require('mobile/keyboard');
```

can anyone tell me why I cannot have the above code like that?

Comment: "I find that I am running into errors" --- any chance you provide those? "can anyone tell me why I cannot have the above code like that" --- you surely can.

Comment: @zerkms I am just getting undefined variables for THEME and KEYBOARD but I dont get them when I dont add the import

Comment: If you use pure js require and import does not exist you have to append a balise <script src="youscript"></script>, except if you use a compiler es6

Comment: @spaceboound why don't you declare `THEME` with `var` or `let` or `const`?

Comment: You do understand that you have to declare the variables first?

Comment: @zerkms I tried that but it fails to bring up my keyboard now

Comment: @AndrewL. I do but I am mostly going off of this tutorial on how to create a dialog box: https://github.com/Kinoma/KPR-examples/tree/master/basic-dialog and they don't declare them and it works fine.

Comment: @spaceboound Are your variables in the global scope? Are you using ES6?

Comment: @AndrewL. Yes I am using ES6 and I understand that using var makes the variable global but regardless, after I run my code, I get # Break: it: get THEME: undefined variable!

Comment: Well, provide complete code where you use it. It definitely **must be** a declaration with `var` or `let` or `const`

Comment: @spaceboound No, using `var`don't makes the variable global. Definitively not. That's why it is not defined in another context.